# Play framework - parse duration parameter in configuration file

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration

Play! official documentation on the configuration file says that it is possible to specify [duration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Configuration#Duration-format) variables using proper keywords.

How do I retrieve those variables in my application? I mean, in order to read a `String` variable I use:

```
val conf = Play.configuration.getString("name.of.the.variable").get
```

But I don't see any `Play.configuration.getDuration()` or similar function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
    val conf: FiniteDuration = Play.configuration.getMilliseconds("foo.bar").get milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val bindTimeout = Play.configuration.get[Duration]("name.of.the.variable")
```

Comment: The `Configuration` class (i.e. the type of the `Play.configuration` object) doesn't have any `get[T](path: String): Option[T]` member function. At least the version of the framework I'm using, that is 2.3.x